# Java - Automatically create play project from code

Tags: java, process, cmd, playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2.2.1 and Java 8.

I am trying to make automation scripts, and one of them includes running the play new command from cmd.

I want to run the play new NAME command, and automatically enter the next arguments that this command requires (project name and Java project).

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? So far I know how to run cmd commands using Process class.

Answer (score 0):

you can write Windows cmd script e.g. `c:\dev\play.cmd` with only this row:

```
activator new projectname play-java
```

where 4th param is project template. See contents of activator.bat.